# How to avoid SIGABRT when generating RSA Signature at EVP_SignFinal

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa, digital-signature

I'm trying to generate a RSA Signature with libopenssl for c++:
But when I run my code, I get a SIGABRT. I did some deep debugging into libopenssl internal stuff to see where the Segfault comes from. I'll come to this later on.

First I want to make clear, that the RSA PrivateKey was successfully loaded from a .pem file. So Im pretty sure that's not the problem's origin.

So my question is: How to avoid the SIGABRT and what is the cause of it ?

I'm doing this for my B.Sc. Thesis so I really appreciate your help :)

---

### Signature Generation Function:

```
DocumentSignature* RSASignatureGenerator::generateSignature(ContentHash* ch, CryptographicKey* pK) throw(PDVSException) {
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

    if(pK == nullptr)
        throw MissingPrivateKeyException();

    if(pK->getKeyType() != CryptographicKey::KeyType::RSA_PRIVATE || !dynamic_cast<RSAPrivateKey*>(pK))
        throw KeyTypeMissmatchException(pK->getPem()->getPath().string(), "Generate RSA Signature");

    //get msg to encrypt
    const char* msg = ch->getStringHash().c_str();

    //get openssl rsa key
    RSA* rsaPK = dynamic_cast<RSAPrivateKey*>(pK)->createOpenSSLRSAKeyObject();

    //create openssl signing context
    EVP_MD_CTX* rsaSignCtx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
    EVP_PKEY* priKey  = EVP_PKEY_new();
    EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(priKey, rsaPK);

    //init ctxt
    if (EVP_SignInit(rsaSignCtx, EVP_sha256()) <=0)
        throw RSASignatureGenerationException();

    //add data to sign
    if (EVP_SignUpdate(rsaSignCtx, msg, std::strlen(msg)) <= 0) {
        throw RSASignatureGenerationException();
    }

    //create result byte signature struct
    DocumentSignature::ByteSignature* byteSig = new DocumentSignature::ByteSignature();
    //set size to max possible
    byteSig->size = EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE;
    //alloc buffer memory
    byteSig->data = (unsigned char*)malloc(byteSig->size);

    //do signing
    if (EVP_SignFinal(rsaSignCtx, byteSig->data, (unsigned int*) &byteSig->size, priKey) <= 0)
        throw RSASignatureGenerationException();


    DocumentSignature* res = new DocumentSignature(ch);
    res->setByteSignature(byteSig);

    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(rsaSignCtx);
    //TODO open SSL Memory leaks -> where to free open ssl stuff?!

    return res;
}
```

### RSA* rsaPK = dynamic_cast(pK)->createOpenSSLRSAKeyObject();

```
virtual RSA* createOpenSSLRSAKeyObject() throw (PDVSException) override {
        RSA* rsa = NULL;
        const char* c_string = _pem->getContent().c_str();
        BIO * keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)c_string, -1);

        if (keybio==NULL)
            throw OpenSSLRSAPrivateKeyObjectCreationException(_pem->getPath());

        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa, NULL, NULL);

        if(rsa == nullptr)
            throw OpenSSLRSAPrivateKeyObjectCreationException(_pem->getPath());

        //BIO_free(keybio);

        return rsa;
    }
```

### SigAbrt origin in file openssl/crypto/mem.c

```
void CRYPTO_free(void *str, const char *file, int line)
{
    if (free_impl != NULL && free_impl != &CRYPTO_free) {
        free_impl(str, file, line);
        return;
    }

#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_CRYPTO_MDEBUG
    if (call_malloc_debug) {
        CRYPTO_mem_debug_free(str, 0, file, line);
        free(str);
        CRYPTO_mem_debug_free(str, 1, file, line);
    } else {
        free(str);
    }
#else
    free(str); // <<<<<<< HERE
#endif
}
```

### the stacktrace

[stacktrace screenshot from debugger (clion - gdb based)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vD12.png)

Comment: The cause of your SIGABRT is a bug somewhere in your code. The only way to avoid it, is to find and fix the bug. Without a [mcve] (the shown code fails both the minimum and the complete part) no further answer will be possible. Due to the way that C++ works, the bug can be anywhere. Just because a program crashes inside one particular function doesn't mean that's where the bug is.

Comment: Hm ok, thanks.. I think i'll have to hunt the bug then.. because when i do a minimalistic example it works.. :(

Comment: Of course it works. That proves that you have a bug somewhere. Of course, a bug in the library is always a possibility. But a very unlikely one. Welcome to C++.

Comment: Also see [EVP Signing and Verifying](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying) on the OpenSSL wiki. You should be able to copy/paste it, and things should "just work" for you. Also, for an example of C-object management from C++, see [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption | C++ Programs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#C.2B.2B_Programs) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: *" I think i'll have to hunt the bug then.. because when i do a minimalistic example it works..."* - Valgrind can usually help, but OpenSSL has so many memory leaks its often difficult to use the tool on OpenSSL. Maybe you can build with the Address Sanitizer and wait for the bad read/write.

Comment: OpenSSL was implemented in c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the Bug (and Im really not sure if this is a libopenssl bug..)

```
//set size to max possible
byteSig->size = EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE;
//alloc buffer memory
byteSig->data = (unsigned char*)malloc(byteSig->size);
```

The problem was when I set the buffer size to EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE!

The (in my opinion) very very strange thing is, that you have to keep the size uninitialized! (not even set to 0 - just "size_t size;" ).

Strange thing here is that then you also HAVE TO allocate memory just like I did. I dont understand this because then an undefined size of memory gets allocated..

What the really weird is that libopenssl internally sets the size back to 0 and allocates the memory itself.. (I detected this by browsing the libopenssl source code)

Comment: Could it be that `byteSig->size` happens to be zero when you leave it uninitialized and that `malloc(0)` returns `NULL`?

Comment: strangly, no. when I debug with gdb an uninitialized size_t is always 1713 on my mashine (Ubuntu 64bit 16.04 LTS). When I init the size to 0 the same error (as posted in the main question occurs)

Comment: You should be aware that you do **not** "have to keep the size uninitialized". It sounds to me like some kind of heap corruption but there cannot be any code relying on a value being "uninitialized" because that is not a defined state.

Comment: I doubt this is the case, but normally in windows physical memory is pointed to by a virtual memory address so it isn't contiguous. I believe a lot of Linux servers use oppenssl and I have heard of attach methods where the attacker has been able to cause an unhandled exception in production versions of oppenssl either causing the server to crash or worse allowing attacker to make use of continuous memory to recover the hidden key often used in ssl to encrypt transmissions over http. Perhaps this was some kind of fix as it is kind of a vulnerability in an o.s. being fixed by the application.

Comment: Basically you aren't supposed to make sense of array overflows for example but people can in some cases. I can see how openssl may want to be picky about where things are allocated.